# Neo4j - Query: combine different query results in one collection with special order

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have got a query like this

```
START a = node:lucene_index('name: "actor1"')
MATCH (a:Actor)--(b:Movies)
WHERE b.director = 'director1'
WITH b LIMIT 4
RETURN 'Movies' AS resultType, collect (DISTINCT b) as resultList

UNION ALL 

START a = node:lucene_index('name: "actor1"')
MATCH (a:Actor)--(b:Movies)
WHERE b.director = 'director2'
WITH b LIMIT 4
RETURN 'Movies' AS resultType, collect (DISTINCT b) as resultList

UNION ALL 

START a = node:lucene_index('name: "actor1"')
MATCH (a:Actor)-[r]-(b:Movies)
WITH b
MATCH (b)-[r2]-(b2:Actor)
WITH b, count(r2) as relations
ORDER BY toInt(relations) DESC
LIMIT 2
RETURN 'Movies' AS resultType, collect (DISTINCT b) as resultList
```

Is is possible to combine those queries to one? 
It is important that the resultList cointains the movies in the order as shown in the query

- 1 - 4 of director1
- 5 - 8 of director2
- 9 - 10 with the most relations to actors

Thank you!

Comment: The syntax you are using is deprecated (`START a = node:(...)`). Which Neo4j version are you using?

Comment: we know about the deprecated indices and hopefully our parsing software (which fills our DB) will be upgraded soon (neo4j version is 3.0.2). (and our DB does not contain movies and actors :) I was just writing an abstract example
but an upgrade wont change the fact that neo4j will fire "MATCH (a:Actor)--(b:Movies)" two times and once with the relation. And I want to figure out if there is a way to collect the differently sorted results in one collection

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at the Neo4j knowledge base article on [post-union processing](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/post-union-processing/). That provides a few approaches to perform your unions, yet be able to perform sorting operations afterwards.

Of course you'll need something to sort on for this. I would add a third field returned for each of these (`order`, for example), and explicitly set this to 1 for your first subquery, 2 for the second, and 3 for the third. Then just sort on that field when processing after the union.